# Completion Suggester - First element of input array gives suggestion well but not the later

Tags: elasticsearch

For completion suggestion, I have input as follow:

```
"input": ["com.google.playstore", "New Playstore"]
```

Let say for query `com.google` or 'com.goo' or `comgoogl`, above works well.
But when searching for `New Playstore` or `new`, suggestion is not displayed.

If input is reversed, the later `New Playstore` or `new` works well but not the `com.google` or 'com.goo' or `comgoogl`.

```
`"input": [ "New Playstore", "com.google.playstore"]`
```

Wondering what could be its reason? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue. What version you are using? can you include all the steps in your question from index creation to query?

Comment: I am using Elasticsearch version 2.4. Please refer this for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275013/elasticsearch-autocomplete-completion-suggestion-from-dot-whitespace-for-mat.

Comment: I have answered the referenced question.